# Rails: GET or POST to get a list of ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a huge list of items with checkboxes beside them allowing a user to select which items they want to print.

When the user has selected a bunch of items, and clicks Print, I'm sending a GET request with the codes built up in the query string:

```
/registration_codes.pdf?ids[]=1&ids[]=5&ids[]=18...
```

The problem is, when this gets too long it throws an exception saying that the query string is too long. Plus, its damn ugly.

Obviously this is an issue with GET, but if I'm to follow 'RESTful' rules, a POST, or even PUT or DELETE doesn't make sense here.

Can anybody suggest a better way to handle this while being RESTful, or should I just break the rules and do a POST instead?

Comment: Can that be done from a form without using javascript?

Comment: no. if however you are submitting a form, then isn't POST the way to go?

Comment: Well, normally, yes. But in REST terms, a POST means you're sending data to the server to create something. A GET request is for retrieving data. Since I'm not changing any data, using a POST request would be breaking the rules of REST. Or maybe I'm being too pedantic

Answer (score 0):

Obvious:

- Change "ids[]=" to "i=" - it would already save you +- 50% of space.
- Use different encoding `ids[]=1,5,18,...`

Also it seems that if you have that many check-boxes... Maybe you are doing something wrong.

There are many other ways to compress the data: bitmap encoded in hexadecimal or base64 representation. Or even pain bitmap may be sufficient and have deterministic length:

```
id=1000100000000010000...
```

Same as hexadecimal

```
id=880fa0...
```

Comment: You're right, having that many checkboxes is wacky. A jQuery UI selectable helps with selecting lots of items at once, but maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: See if you have for example 1 checkbox that implies 20 others selected... Than you don't need to pass all 20 others.

Comment: They are all individual items meaning the user could select any combination of the items - none of them are related to each other. I think you're right though, I should be looking at another way of selecting these items. I'm thinking tagging or marking the items before proceeding to the printing stage.

Still interested in hearing if anybody has any other ideas.